# How to get the fields and it's count (Occurances) in a table in sqlite(Android)?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm showing a multichoice list view from an arraylist (max 130 values). The user has to select 1 to 5 items in the list, I'm inserting them (selected items) in a database after selection in a button click. it works fine.

Table Structure :

```
private static final String CREATE_SELECTED_CAND_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + TABLE_SELECTED_CAND
        + "("
        + KEY_ID
        + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
        + KEY_NAME1
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME2
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME3
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME4
        + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME5 + " TEXT" + ")";
```

and this is how i'm inserting into the table :

```
public long insertCandidates(DataSelectedCandidates dataSelCand) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME1, dataSelCand.getmCandidateName1());
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME2, dataSelCand.getmCandidateName2());
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME3, dataSelCand.getmCandidateName3());
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME4, dataSelCand.getmCandidateName4());
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME5, dataSelCand.getmCandidateName5());
    return mDb.insert(TABLE_SELECTED_CAND, null, initialValues);

}
```

I'm inserting records for multiple times. say for ex : "james" can be in 1st,5th and 8th row or james cannot be available in the database.

How can i get the name field and its count(occurances in the database)? i need to show that in another list.!

I'm getting all the values with the cursor :

```
Selected_candidDB.open();
Cursor cursor = Selected_candidDB.fetchAllCandidates();
```

Can i achieve this with the above cursor..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use raw sql query to achieve that like:

```
select count(*),name from candidates where name ='james'
```

it will return a result :   |  number of occuence  |  name|